# How to run a macro in Word after paste?

Tags: vba, ms-word

How do I make Microsoft Word to run a macro every time every time the user paste text?

I have recorded this macro:

```
Sub AdjustFontSize()
'
' AdjustFontSize Macro
' Adjusts font size
'
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 24
End Sub
```

This changes the font size of everything in the document, and I want that to happen when the user is pasting text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code.

```
Sub EditPaste()
    Selection.Paste
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Font.Size = 24
End Sub
```

`EditPaste` is an in-built command. You can find it here.

[image]

[image]

What I did is to overwrite the existing command and added my code into it.